# Как парсить svg который рендерится через js(ajax)?

Tags: python, парсер, svg, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Такая проблема, что на сайте стоит капча которая немного меняется с помощью js , меняет свое положение.
При парсинге получается обрезанная капча на половину. Но если svg-код сохранить в html-файл, то капча отображается нормально.
Вот так выглядит в .svg-файле:
[image: svg]
Так выглядит в html-файле:
[image: html]
код капчи:

```
<svg height="100%" version="1.1" viewbox="-35,75,100,60" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M-29.7 80 l-2.19 0 q1.25 1.87 -1.56 0.62 l-1.87 1.87 q1.24 2.18 -0.62 0.93 l-0.93 4.35 l-1.24 -6.2 q1.55 0.31 -1.86 -1.55 l-2.17 0 q1.24 1.85 -0.93 0.31 l-2.16 2.16 q1.54 2.16 -0.31 1.23 l4.31 15.69 q2.15 3.07 0 2.46 l-1.23 3.99 q1.84 1.84 0 0.31 q1.84 3.06 1.22 1.22 l2.45 0 q2.75 1.83 1.53 -0.92 l1.83 -1.83 q2.44 1.22 0.61 -0.91 l6.08 -22.19 q1.82 1.52 0 -0.3 q1.82 0.61 -1.21 -1.21 z M-36.94 104.43 l-2.12 0 q0.91 1.81 -0.91 -0.91 l1.21 -3.92 q2.41 0.3 0 -2.71 l-3.91 -14.44 l0.6 0 q3.01 1.8 1.5 1.2 l2.4 10.8 q2.1 2.1 0.3 0.3 t0.3 0 l1.79 -2.09 q2.09 1.49 0.3 -0.6 l2.09 -9.84 l1.49 0 q2.98 1.79 0.89 1.19 z M-35.99 92.16 l-1.49 1.49 l0.89 -3.86 z M-35.31 83.04 q2.08 0.59 1.48 -1.18 l-2.07 9.17 l-0.59 -2.66 z M-41.96 79.76 l2.07 0 q3.25 1.77 1.47 1.18 l1.47 7.36 l-1.18 4.71 l-2.06 -10.29 q1.47 0.29 -2.06 -1.47 l-0.59 0 l-0.29 -0.59 q1.76 0.59 0.88 -1.17 z M-43.3 81.02 l0 0.58 l-0.88 0 l0.88 -0.58 q2.04 1.75 0 0.29 z M-41.07 106.28 q0.87 1.75 -0.87 -0.87 l1.16 -4.07 q2.32 0.29 0 -2.9 l-4.06 -15.36 q1.74 0.58 0.87 -1.16 l1.16 0 l3.76 14.45 q2.31 2.89 0 2.6 l-1.15 4.04 q1.73 2.02 0 0.29 q2.02 2.88 1.44 1.15 l2.01 0 q1.72 2.01 0 0.57 q1.72 2.87 -1.43 1.15 l-2.58 0 z M-28.63 80.71 l-6.29 22.31 q1.72 2.57 -1.43 1.14 l6 -21.12 q2 1.43 0 -0.29 q1.99 0.57 -1.42 -1.14 l-1.42 0 l0 -0.28 q2.27 0.57 1.42 -1.14 l1.99 0 q3.12 1.7 0.85 1.13 z M-7.36 97.1 q1.42 0.28 -0.57 -7.35 q1.98 -2.54 -3.11 -5.08 l0.28 -0.28 q4.8 0.28 3.1 -5.92 q1.97 -1.13 -2.53 -4.78 t-5.35 -1.97 l-7.03 0 q1.4 1.69 -1.4 0.56 l-2.24 2.24 q1.4 2.24 -0.56 1.12 l0 22.96 q1.96 2.52 0.56 1.12 t1.12 0.56 l2.51 0 q2.51 1.67 1.39 -0.56 l1.95 -1.95 q2.51 1.11 0.56 -1.11 l0 -6.4 q4.45 2.5 2.5 5.28 q1.94 3.33 0.28 3.61 q2.22 3.33 1.94 1.66 l3.6 0 q2.22 1.66 0.28 0 l2.21 -2.21 q2.21 1.38 0 -0.28 z M-9.66 99.36 q1.66 1.1 -0.28 -1.65 l1.65 0 z M-8.54 90.04 q1.93 7.15 0.55 7.15 l-2.2 0 q1.65 -0.55 -0.27 -4.94 q1.92 0 -0.82 -3.29 q0.82 0 -2.74 -1.92 q3.56 1.09 2.46 -1.64 q4.92 2.46 3.01 4.65 z M-18.58 87.4 l-1.91 1.91 q1.36 2.46 -0.55 1.36 l0 6.81 l-1.63 0 q0.82 1.63 -1.09 -1.09 l0 -22.02 l5.98 0 q4.62 1.63 4.89 1.9 t2.17 4.61 q1.9 3.8 -0.54 3.52 q1.35 1.9 -1.62 0.81 l-1.89 1.89 q1.62 1.89 -0.27 0.27 q1.89 2.16 1.08 0.54 t2.16 1.08 q2.97 2.97 1.08 3.5 q1.89 4.31 0.27 5.12 l-1.08 0 q0.81 1.61 -1.34 -1.08 q1.61 -0.27 -0.27 -3.49 q1.88 -4.29 -4.02 -5.9 q1.34 1.61 -1.34 0.54 z M-19.02 88.91 l0 0.54 q1.61 1.61 -0.53 0 z M-12.56 85.79 q2.14 1.87 0.53 0 q1.07 2.67 -1.87 1.33 z M-15.73 72.77 q4.53 1.86 5.06 1.86 t2.4 4.52 q1.86 5.59 -2.13 5.32 q2.39 0.53 0.53 -3.19 q1.86 -1.06 -2.39 -5.04 t-5.31 -2.12 l-6.1 0 l0 -0.53 q1.85 0.53 1.06 -1.06 l7.15 0 z M-24.6 74.58 l-0.53 0 l0.53 -0.53 l0 0.53 z M-25.34 100.83 q0.79 1.85 -1.06 -1.05 l0 -23.19 q1.84 0.53 1.05 -1.05 l0.53 0 l0 22.1 q1.84 2.37 0.53 1.31 t1.31 0.53 l1.58 0 l0 0.52 q1.84 2.89 -1.31 1.05 l-2.62 0 z M-20.96 99.29 l0.52 0 l-0.52 0.52 l0 -0.52 z M-19.35 97.8 q1.83 2.88 -1.05 1.05 l-0.52 0 l0 -6.79 q1.83 0.52 1.04 -1.04 q2.35 1.82 0.52 0 l0 6.77 z M-15.36 100.22 q1.56 -0.26 -0.26 -3.64 q1.82 -3.12 -3.12 -5.72 l0 -0.78 q2.08 1.3 0.26 -0.78 t0.78 -0.26 q5.71 1.82 3.63 5.44 q2.07 3.37 0.26 3.63 q2.33 3.37 1.81 1.55 l1.03 0 q2.07 2.84 0.26 1.81 l-3.62 0 q0.77 1.81 -1.55 -1.29 z M-17.29 86.17 l2.06 -2.06 q3.35 0.26 1.55 -2.83 q2.06 -2.06 -3.09 -3.86 l-1.03 0 q1.29 1.8 -1.29 0.51 l-2.31 2.31 q1.54 2.31 -0.51 1.28 l0 4.36 q2.05 2.57 0.51 1.28 t1.03 0.51 q3.59 1.79 3.08 -1.54 z M-17.93 78.11 l1.02 0 q4.61 1.79 2.56 3.33 q2.05 3.58 -1.79 3.07 q2.04 1.53 0 -0.77 q2.04 -1.79 -3.06 -3.83 l0 -0.51 q2.04 0.51 1.27 -1.27 z M-19.62 80.27 l-0.51 0 l0.51 -0.51 l0 0.51 z M-19.09 80.91 q4.32 1.78 2.54 3.31 q2.03 2.29 -0.25 1.02 q1.27 2.03 -1.27 0.25 q1.02 1.78 -1.01 -1.27 l0 -3.3 z M-20.54 87.96 q1.01 1.77 -1.01 -1.27 l0 -4.56 q2.03 0.51 1.27 -1.27 l0.51 0 l0 3.29 q2.02 2.53 0.51 1.26 t1.01 0.51 q2.53 1.77 1.01 -0.25 q0.76 3.78 -3.28 2.02 z M-2.52 78.67 q0.25 3.53 -2.27 5.04 q1.76 3.78 -0.25 6.55 q2.01 6.04 0.25 6.29 q2.52 5.53 2.26 5.53 q4.27 4.02 7.04 2.26 q2.76 1.76 2.26 0 t2.26 0 l5.02 0 q2.76 1.76 1 -0.5 l2.51 -2.51 q2.51 1.25 0.5 -1.25 l0 -1.25 q2 1.25 -0.5 -1.25 t-1.25 -0.5 l-1 0 q1.5 1.75 -2 0.5 q4.5 -1 2.5 -9.74 q2 -3 -0.25 -6.74 q1.5 -1.5 -2.25 -5.24 q-0.25 -0.5 -6.98 -2.24 q-2.74 1.74 -6.98 2.49 z M15.94 98.89 l1 0 q3.24 1.74 1.24 1.24 l0 1.24 q1.99 2.98 -1.24 1.24 l-0.75 0 q1.99 0 -1.74 -1.74 l-0.99 0 q1.49 1.74 -1.99 0.5 q2.73 1.24 1.49 -1.49 q2.48 1.74 1.24 -0.5 t1.49 -0.5 z M16.85 103.56 l-0.5 0.5 l0 -0.5 l0.5 0 z M13.86 92.3 q1.98 8.16 -2.23 9.15 l-0.99 0.99 q1.73 1.98 0 0.49 q1.98 1.98 0.25 0 q2.22 1.73 1.48 -0.49 t1.48 -0.49 l0.99 0 q3.21 1.73 1.23 1.23 l-3.94 0 q1.23 1.72 -2.46 0 t-2.46 0 q-2.71 1.72 -6.89 -1.97 q0.49 0.25 -2.21 -5.41 q1.72 -0.25 -0.25 -6.15 q1.97 -5.9 1.47 -10.57 q4.18 0.74 5.4 -1.23 q6.63 1.96 6.63 2.21 q3.68 3.68 2.21 5.15 q2.45 3.92 0.25 6.87 z M14.47 93.42 q1.96 -2.94 -0.25 -6.86 q1.47 -1.71 -2.45 -5.39 q-0.24 -0.49 -7.1 -2.45 q-0.73 1.96 -4.89 0.73 q4.16 -0.98 7.34 -2.69 q6.6 1.96 6.85 2.2 q3.67 3.67 2.2 5.13 q2.44 3.91 0.24 6.84 q1.95 9.28 -3.17 10.01 q3.17 -0.73 1.22 -7.81 z M9.76 107.81 q1.22 1.95 -2.44 0.24 t-2.44 0.24 q-2.68 1.95 -6.82 -2.19 q0.24 0.24 -2.19 -5.6 q1.7 -0.24 -0.24 -6.33 q2.19 -2.92 0.24 -6.81 q2.68 -1.46 2.19 -5.11 q2.43 1.46 0.73 -0.49 q0.97 4.62 -1.21 9.96 q2.19 6.32 0.24 6.56 q2.67 5.83 2.43 5.83 q4.37 4.13 7.28 2.18 q2.91 1.94 2.43 -0.24 t2.43 -0.24 l4.12 0 l0 0.73 q2.18 3.15 -1.21 1.21 l-5.33 0 z M7.27 82.1 q0.48 1.94 -2.42 0.73 l-2.66 2.66 q1.21 2.9 -1.21 3.39 q1.94 3.63 -0.24 6.05 q2.18 9.91 1.69 9.67 q2.9 2.66 2.42 0.97 q3.62 1.93 2.17 -0.72 l2.66 -2.66 q3.62 0.24 1.69 -9.66 q2.17 -6.28 -1.69 -9.89 q1.21 0.97 -2.41 -0.96 z M1.45 100.57 q1.93 0.24 0 -4.58 q2.17 -6.03 1.45 -9.4 q2.41 1.45 0.96 -0.48 q1.69 4.09 -0.48 7.71 q2.17 9.87 1.69 9.63 q3.13 2.89 2.65 0.96 q1.44 3.85 -2.89 1.92 q0.24 1.92 -2.65 -1.92 q1.68 0.96 -0.72 -3.61 z M7.69 104.55 q0.48 2.16 -2.4 -0.72 q0.72 0.48 -1.44 -9.37 q2.16 -3.84 0.48 -7.68 q3.84 1.68 2.4 0.72 q3.6 3.36 1.44 9.6 q2.16 7.44 -0.48 7.68 z M9.59 104.08 q1.44 2.64 -1.2 0.72 q2.64 -0.24 0.48 -7.43 q2.16 -6.47 -1.68 -10.06 q1.2 0.96 -2.87 -0.96 q2.87 0 2.87 -1.92 q4.07 1.92 2.87 1.91 q2.63 3.11 0.72 3.83 q2.39 3.83 0.24 4.78 q2.15 10.05 -1.43 9.33 z M46.39 109.98 q2.63 1.43 0.24 -1.43 l-7.17 -26.29 q1.67 0.24 -2.39 -1.67 l-5.02 0 q1.19 1.91 -1.91 0.96 l-2.39 2.15 q1.67 2.39 -0.72 0.95 l-7.4 26.49 q2.15 2.15 0 0.48 q2.15 3.34 1.43 1.43 l2.86 0 q3.1 1.91 1.91 -1.19 l1.91 -1.91 q2.86 1.19 0.95 -1.19 l0.48 -2.38 l4.77 0 q3.57 1.91 1.67 1.43 l0.95 3.57 q2.62 3.81 2.38 1.91 l3.33 0 q2.86 1.9 1.19 -0.48 z M37.85 82.35 q3.57 1.9 1.67 1.43 l7.38 26.89 q2.38 2.38 -0.24 0.95 t-0.71 0.48 l-1.19 0 l-7.13 -25.92 q1.66 0.24 -2.38 -1.9 l-4.52 0 l0.24 -0.48 q2.61 0.71 1.9 -1.43 l4.99 0 z M45.14 113.32 l0.95 0 l-0.71 0.71 q2.14 1.9 -0.24 -0.71 z M30.87 107.08 l-2.37 2.37 q1.66 2.61 -0.71 0.95 l-0.71 2.37 l-2.61 0 q0.95 1.9 -0.95 -1.19 l7.12 -26.1 l4.74 0 q3.56 1.9 1.9 1.42 l7.11 26.09 l-1.42 0 q0.71 2.13 -1.9 -1.42 l-0.95 -3.56 q1.66 0.24 -2.37 -1.9 l-5.45 0 q1.18 2.13 -1.9 0.95 z M22.51 116.56 q0.95 2.13 -0.95 -1.18 l7.58 -27.47 q2.61 0.95 1.66 -1.42 l-7.34 26.05 q2.13 2.13 0 0.47 q2.13 3.55 1.66 1.42 l2.37 0 l0 0.47 q1.89 3.55 -1.89 1.42 l-3.08 0 z M30.05 113.56 q1.89 3.31 -1.66 1.42 l0.71 -2.37 q2.6 0.95 1.66 -1.42 z M41.38 118 q0.71 2.13 -1.89 -1.42 l-0.95 -3.55 q1.89 0.24 -2.36 -1.89 l-4.96 0 l0.24 -0.47 q2.6 0.71 1.89 -1.42 l5.44 0 q3.78 2.13 1.89 1.42 l0.95 3.54 q2.83 4.02 2.36 1.89 l1.65 0 l0.24 0.71 q2.6 3.31 -0.94 1.18 l-3.54 0 z M36.37 107.68 l2.6 -2.6 q2.83 1.42 0.47 -1.65 l-2.36 -10.15 q1.89 0.24 -0.71 -1.89 q2.12 2.12 -0.24 0.24 l-2.36 2.36 q1.89 2.36 -0.47 0.47 t-0.47 1.65 l-2.12 10.15 q2.12 2.83 0.24 1.42 t1.42 0.71 l2.83 0 q3.07 2.12 0.94 -0.24 z M37.5 107.08 l0 -0.47 l0.94 0 l-0.94 0.71 l0 -0.24 z M39.62 104.94 q2.59 3.54 -0.94 1.41 l-1.18 0 l-1.65 -6.6 l1.18 -5.66 z M36.78 106.8 l-0.94 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.18 -1.41 l0.94 -3.77 z M35.59 99 l-0.71 -2.83 l1.65 -1.65 z M32.29 108.41 l2.36 -11.08 l0.71 3.06 l-1.18 5.18 q2.12 3.06 0.24 1.41 t1.41 0.71 l1.18 0 l0.24 0.71 q2.59 3.53 -0.94 1.41 l-2.83 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.18 -1.41 z M76.56 88.11 l-3.3 0 q1.18 2.12 -2.12 0.94 l-2.59 2.59 q1.65 2.83 -0.94 1.18 l-2.12 5.89 l-3.06 -8.48 q1.65 0.24 -2.59 -1.88 l-3.77 0 q1.65 2.12 -1.18 0.24 l-3.06 3.06 q1.88 2.59 0 1.41 l7.06 17.66 q3.06 3.77 0.71 3.3 l0 7.77 q2.35 3.06 0.71 1.41 t1.41 0.71 l3.3 0 q3.3 2.12 1.41 -0.71 l2.83 -2.83 q3.06 1.65 0.71 -1.41 l0 -7.77 q2.35 0.47 0.71 -3.3 l7.77 -17.66 q2.59 1.65 0 -0.71 q2.35 0.94 -1.41 -1.41 z M67.58 122.44 l-1.88 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.41 -1.41 l0 -7.77 q2.35 0.24 -0.71 -3.53 l-6.59 -16.25 l1.18 0 q4 2.12 2.12 1.41 l3.77 10.36 q2.83 3.3 0.71 0.94 l0 0 q2.83 2.12 0.47 -0.24 l2.83 -2.83 q2.59 1.88 0.47 -0.71 l3.53 -8.95 l3.3 0 q3.77 2.12 0.71 1.18 l-7.77 18.13 q1.65 4 -0.71 3.53 l0 6.36 z M68.06 104.09 q2.59 2.59 0.47 0.71 l-1.18 1.18 z M71.13 96.8 q2.83 1.18 1.65 -1.41 l-3.3 8.71 q2.36 2.59 -0.47 0.47 q2.36 2.12 -0.24 -0.47 l-0.24 -0.71 z M62.66 92.81 q4 2.12 2.12 1.41 l3.53 9.66 l-1.41 3.53 q2.36 2.59 -0.47 0.47 q2.36 2.12 -0.24 -0.47 l-3.77 -10.6 q1.89 0.24 -2.83 -1.89 l-1.41 0 l-0.47 -0.94 q1.89 0.94 0.94 -1.18 l4.01 0 z M57.74 95.45 l0.24 0.71 l-1.65 0 l1.18 -1.18 q2.59 2.36 0.24 0.47 z M68.6 130.13 l-3.54 0 q0.94 2.36 -1.41 -1.41 l0 -8.02 q2.59 0.24 -0.71 -3.77 l-7.55 -18.63 q1.89 0.94 0.94 -1.18 l2.12 0 l6.84 17.22 q3.07 4.01 0.71 3.54 l0 8.02 q2.59 3.3 0.71 1.65 t1.65 0.71 l1.89 0 l0 0.71 q2.6 3.78 -1.42 1.42 z M71.73 129.55 l0.71 0 l-0.71 0.71 l0 -0.71 z M83.31 97.01 l-8.26 18.88 q1.89 4.01 -0.71 3.78 l0 8.26 q2.6 3.78 -1.42 1.42 l-0.71 0 l0 -6.85 q2.6 0.47 0.71 -3.54 l8.27 -18.89 q2.6 1.89 0.24 -0.71 q2.6 0.94 -1.65 -1.42 l-3.07 0 l0.24 -0.71 q3.07 0.71 2.13 -1.65 l3.54 0 q4.02 2.36 0.95 1.18 z " fill="none" stroke="black"></path></svg>
```

Как отправить такую капчу на anti-captcha или сохранять в адекватном виде в .svg/.png?

Comment: вы, наверно, уже догадались, что картинка-то в файле записана целиком, и только отображается со сдвигом. ну, либо картинки всё-таки две.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да верно. Но игра с viewbox не дает результата вообще. Их две, верно, но беру нужную, она обернута в <figure>. По нему ее и вытаскиваю. Плюсом я изменил height с 100px на 100%, но и на 100px ее в html файле видно нормально... 
Буду благодарен если направите в направление куда рыться далее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы на правильном пути: всё дело в неправильных значениях параметров **viewBox**;
Методом "тыка" подобрать правильные значения параметров, практически невозможно.

Решить эту задачу поможет метод JS getBBox();

```
<script>
let  bb = captcha.getBBox();
console.log(bb);
</script>
```

```html
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" viewbox="-45.5 71.2 130.4  60.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <path id="captcha" d="M-29.7 80 l-2.19 0 q1.25 1.87 -1.56 0.62 l-1.87 1.87 q1.24 2.18 -0.62 0.93 l-0.93 4.35 l-1.24 -6.2 q1.55 0.31 -1.86 -1.55 l-2.17 0 q1.24 1.85 -0.93 0.31 l-2.16 2.16 q1.54 2.16 -0.31 1.23 l4.31 15.69 q2.15 3.07 0 2.46 l-1.23 3.99 q1.84 1.84 0 0.31 q1.84 3.06 1.22 1.22 l2.45 0 q2.75 1.83 1.53 -0.92 l1.83 -1.83 q2.44 1.22 0.61 -0.91 l6.08 -22.19 q1.82 1.52 0 -0.3 q1.82 0.61 -1.21 -1.21 z M-36.94 104.43 l-2.12 0 q0.91 1.81 -0.91 -0.91 l1.21 -3.92 q2.41 0.3 0 -2.71 l-3.91 -14.44 l0.6 0 q3.01 1.8 1.5 1.2 l2.4 10.8 q2.1 2.1 0.3 0.3 t0.3 0 l1.79 -2.09 q2.09 1.49 0.3 -0.6 l2.09 -9.84 l1.49 0 q2.98 1.79 0.89 1.19 z M-35.99 92.16 l-1.49 1.49 l0.89 -3.86 z M-35.31 83.04 q2.08 0.59 1.48 -1.18 l-2.07 9.17 l-0.59 -2.66 z M-41.96 79.76 l2.07 0 q3.25 1.77 1.47 1.18 l1.47 7.36 l-1.18 4.71 l-2.06 -10.29 q1.47 0.29 -2.06 -1.47 l-0.59 0 l-0.29 -0.59 q1.76 0.59 0.88 -1.17 z M-43.3 81.02 l0 0.58 l-0.88 0 l0.88 -0.58 q2.04 1.75 0 0.29 z M-41.07 106.28 q0.87 1.75 -0.87 -0.87 l1.16 -4.07 q2.32 0.29 0 -2.9 l-4.06 -15.36 q1.74 0.58 0.87 -1.16 l1.16 0 l3.76 14.45 q2.31 2.89 0 2.6 l-1.15 4.04 q1.73 2.02 0 0.29 q2.02 2.88 1.44 1.15 l2.01 0 q1.72 2.01 0 0.57 q1.72 2.87 -1.43 1.15 l-2.58 0 z M-28.63 80.71 l-6.29 22.31 q1.72 2.57 -1.43 1.14 l6 -21.12 q2 1.43 0 -0.29 q1.99 0.57 -1.42 -1.14 l-1.42 0 l0 -0.28 q2.27 0.57 1.42 -1.14 l1.99 0 q3.12 1.7 0.85 1.13 z M-7.36 97.1 q1.42 0.28 -0.57 -7.35 q1.98 -2.54 -3.11 -5.08 l0.28 -0.28 q4.8 0.28 3.1 -5.92 q1.97 -1.13 -2.53 -4.78 t-5.35 -1.97 l-7.03 0 q1.4 1.69 -1.4 0.56 l-2.24 2.24 q1.4 2.24 -0.56 1.12 l0 22.96 q1.96 2.52 0.56 1.12 t1.12 0.56 l2.51 0 q2.51 1.67 1.39 -0.56 l1.95 -1.95 q2.51 1.11 0.56 -1.11 l0 -6.4 q4.45 2.5 2.5 5.28 q1.94 3.33 0.28 3.61 q2.22 3.33 1.94 1.66 l3.6 0 q2.22 1.66 0.28 0 l2.21 -2.21 q2.21 1.38 0 -0.28 z M-9.66 99.36 q1.66 1.1 -0.28 -1.65 l1.65 0 z M-8.54 90.04 q1.93 7.15 0.55 7.15 l-2.2 0 q1.65 -0.55 -0.27 -4.94 q1.92 0 -0.82 -3.29 q0.82 0 -2.74 -1.92 q3.56 1.09 2.46 -1.64 q4.92 2.46 3.01 4.65 z M-18.58 87.4 l-1.91 1.91 q1.36 2.46 -0.55 1.36 l0 6.81 l-1.63 0 q0.82 1.63 -1.09 -1.09 l0 -22.02 l5.98 0 q4.62 1.63 4.89 1.9 t2.17 4.61 q1.9 3.8 -0.54 3.52 q1.35 1.9 -1.62 0.81 l-1.89 1.89 q1.62 1.89 -0.27 0.27 q1.89 2.16 1.08 0.54 t2.16 1.08 q2.97 2.97 1.08 3.5 q1.89 4.31 0.27 5.12 l-1.08 0 q0.81 1.61 -1.34 -1.08 q1.61 -0.27 -0.27 -3.49 q1.88 -4.29 -4.02 -5.9 q1.34 1.61 -1.34 0.54 z M-19.02 88.91 l0 0.54 q1.61 1.61 -0.53 0 z M-12.56 85.79 q2.14 1.87 0.53 0 q1.07 2.67 -1.87 1.33 z M-15.73 72.77 q4.53 1.86 5.06 1.86 t2.4 4.52 q1.86 5.59 -2.13 5.32 q2.39 0.53 0.53 -3.19 q1.86 -1.06 -2.39 -5.04 t-5.31 -2.12 l-6.1 0 l0 -0.53 q1.85 0.53 1.06 -1.06 l7.15 0 z M-24.6 74.58 l-0.53 0 l0.53 -0.53 l0 0.53 z M-25.34 100.83 q0.79 1.85 -1.06 -1.05 l0 -23.19 q1.84 0.53 1.05 -1.05 l0.53 0 l0 22.1 q1.84 2.37 0.53 1.31 t1.31 0.53 l1.58 0 l0 0.52 q1.84 2.89 -1.31 1.05 l-2.62 0 z M-20.96 99.29 l0.52 0 l-0.52 0.52 l0 -0.52 z M-19.35 97.8 q1.83 2.88 -1.05 1.05 l-0.52 0 l0 -6.79 q1.83 0.52 1.04 -1.04 q2.35 1.82 0.52 0 l0 6.77 z M-15.36 100.22 q1.56 -0.26 -0.26 -3.64 q1.82 -3.12 -3.12 -5.72 l0 -0.78 q2.08 1.3 0.26 -0.78 t0.78 -0.26 q5.71 1.82 3.63 5.44 q2.07 3.37 0.26 3.63 q2.33 3.37 1.81 1.55 l1.03 0 q2.07 2.84 0.26 1.81 l-3.62 0 q0.77 1.81 -1.55 -1.29 z M-17.29 86.17 l2.06 -2.06 q3.35 0.26 1.55 -2.83 q2.06 -2.06 -3.09 -3.86 l-1.03 0 q1.29 1.8 -1.29 0.51 l-2.31 2.31 q1.54 2.31 -0.51 1.28 l0 4.36 q2.05 2.57 0.51 1.28 t1.03 0.51 q3.59 1.79 3.08 -1.54 z M-17.93 78.11 l1.02 0 q4.61 1.79 2.56 3.33 q2.05 3.58 -1.79 3.07 q2.04 1.53 0 -0.77 q2.04 -1.79 -3.06 -3.83 l0 -0.51 q2.04 0.51 1.27 -1.27 z M-19.62 80.27 l-0.51 0 l0.51 -0.51 l0 0.51 z M-19.09 80.91 q4.32 1.78 2.54 3.31 q2.03 2.29 -0.25 1.02 q1.27 2.03 -1.27 0.25 q1.02 1.78 -1.01 -1.27 l0 -3.3 z M-20.54 87.96 q1.01 1.77 -1.01 -1.27 l0 -4.56 q2.03 0.51 1.27 -1.27 l0.51 0 l0 3.29 q2.02 2.53 0.51 1.26 t1.01 0.51 q2.53 1.77 1.01 -0.25 q0.76 3.78 -3.28 2.02 z M-2.52 78.67 q0.25 3.53 -2.27 5.04 q1.76 3.78 -0.25 6.55 q2.01 6.04 0.25 6.29 q2.52 5.53 2.26 5.53 q4.27 4.02 7.04 2.26 q2.76 1.76 2.26 0 t2.26 0 l5.02 0 q2.76 1.76 1 -0.5 l2.51 -2.51 q2.51 1.25 0.5 -1.25 l0 -1.25 q2 1.25 -0.5 -1.25 t-1.25 -0.5 l-1 0 q1.5 1.75 -2 0.5 q4.5 -1 2.5 -9.74 q2 -3 -0.25 -6.74 q1.5 -1.5 -2.25 -5.24 q-0.25 -0.5 -6.98 -2.24 q-2.74 1.74 -6.98 2.49 z M15.94 98.89 l1 0 q3.24 1.74 1.24 1.24 l0 1.24 q1.99 2.98 -1.24 1.24 l-0.75 0 q1.99 0 -1.74 -1.74 l-0.99 0 q1.49 1.74 -1.99 0.5 q2.73 1.24 1.49 -1.49 q2.48 1.74 1.24 -0.5 t1.49 -0.5 z M16.85 103.56 l-0.5 0.5 l0 -0.5 l0.5 0 z M13.86 92.3 q1.98 8.16 -2.23 9.15 l-0.99 0.99 q1.73 1.98 0 0.49 q1.98 1.98 0.25 0 q2.22 1.73 1.48 -0.49 t1.48 -0.49 l0.99 0 q3.21 1.73 1.23 1.23 l-3.94 0 q1.23 1.72 -2.46 0 t-2.46 0 q-2.71 1.72 -6.89 -1.97 q0.49 0.25 -2.21 -5.41 q1.72 -0.25 -0.25 -6.15 q1.97 -5.9 1.47 -10.57 q4.18 0.74 5.4 -1.23 q6.63 1.96 6.63 2.21 q3.68 3.68 2.21 5.15 q2.45 3.92 0.25 6.87 z M14.47 93.42 q1.96 -2.94 -0.25 -6.86 q1.47 -1.71 -2.45 -5.39 q-0.24 -0.49 -7.1 -2.45 q-0.73 1.96 -4.89 0.73 q4.16 -0.98 7.34 -2.69 q6.6 1.96 6.85 2.2 q3.67 3.67 2.2 5.13 q2.44 3.91 0.24 6.84 q1.95 9.28 -3.17 10.01 q3.17 -0.73 1.22 -7.81 z M9.76 107.81 q1.22 1.95 -2.44 0.24 t-2.44 0.24 q-2.68 1.95 -6.82 -2.19 q0.24 0.24 -2.19 -5.6 q1.7 -0.24 -0.24 -6.33 q2.19 -2.92 0.24 -6.81 q2.68 -1.46 2.19 -5.11 q2.43 1.46 0.73 -0.49 q0.97 4.62 -1.21 9.96 q2.19 6.32 0.24 6.56 q2.67 5.83 2.43 5.83 q4.37 4.13 7.28 2.18 q2.91 1.94 2.43 -0.24 t2.43 -0.24 l4.12 0 l0 0.73 q2.18 3.15 -1.21 1.21 l-5.33 0 z M7.27 82.1 q0.48 1.94 -2.42 0.73 l-2.66 2.66 q1.21 2.9 -1.21 3.39 q1.94 3.63 -0.24 6.05 q2.18 9.91 1.69 9.67 q2.9 2.66 2.42 0.97 q3.62 1.93 2.17 -0.72 l2.66 -2.66 q3.62 0.24 1.69 -9.66 q2.17 -6.28 -1.69 -9.89 q1.21 0.97 -2.41 -0.96 z M1.45 100.57 q1.93 0.24 0 -4.58 q2.17 -6.03 1.45 -9.4 q2.41 1.45 0.96 -0.48 q1.69 4.09 -0.48 7.71 q2.17 9.87 1.69 9.63 q3.13 2.89 2.65 0.96 q1.44 3.85 -2.89 1.92 q0.24 1.92 -2.65 -1.92 q1.68 0.96 -0.72 -3.61 z M7.69 104.55 q0.48 2.16 -2.4 -0.72 q0.72 0.48 -1.44 -9.37 q2.16 -3.84 0.48 -7.68 q3.84 1.68 2.4 0.72 q3.6 3.36 1.44 9.6 q2.16 7.44 -0.48 7.68 z M9.59 104.08 q1.44 2.64 -1.2 0.72 q2.64 -0.24 0.48 -7.43 q2.16 -6.47 -1.68 -10.06 q1.2 0.96 -2.87 -0.96 q2.87 0 2.87 -1.92 q4.07 1.92 2.87 1.91 q2.63 3.11 0.72 3.83 q2.39 3.83 0.24 4.78 q2.15 10.05 -1.43 9.33 z M46.39 109.98 q2.63 1.43 0.24 -1.43 l-7.17 -26.29 q1.67 0.24 -2.39 -1.67 l-5.02 0 q1.19 1.91 -1.91 0.96 l-2.39 2.15 q1.67 2.39 -0.72 0.95 l-7.4 26.49 q2.15 2.15 0 0.48 q2.15 3.34 1.43 1.43 l2.86 0 q3.1 1.91 1.91 -1.19 l1.91 -1.91 q2.86 1.19 0.95 -1.19 l0.48 -2.38 l4.77 0 q3.57 1.91 1.67 1.43 l0.95 3.57 q2.62 3.81 2.38 1.91 l3.33 0 q2.86 1.9 1.19 -0.48 z M37.85 82.35 q3.57 1.9 1.67 1.43 l7.38 26.89 q2.38 2.38 -0.24 0.95 t-0.71 0.48 l-1.19 0 l-7.13 -25.92 q1.66 0.24 -2.38 -1.9 l-4.52 0 l0.24 -0.48 q2.61 0.71 1.9 -1.43 l4.99 0 z M45.14 113.32 l0.95 0 l-0.71 0.71 q2.14 1.9 -0.24 -0.71 z M30.87 107.08 l-2.37 2.37 q1.66 2.61 -0.71 0.95 l-0.71 2.37 l-2.61 0 q0.95 1.9 -0.95 -1.19 l7.12 -26.1 l4.74 0 q3.56 1.9 1.9 1.42 l7.11 26.09 l-1.42 0 q0.71 2.13 -1.9 -1.42 l-0.95 -3.56 q1.66 0.24 -2.37 -1.9 l-5.45 0 q1.18 2.13 -1.9 0.95 z M22.51 116.56 q0.95 2.13 -0.95 -1.18 l7.58 -27.47 q2.61 0.95 1.66 -1.42 l-7.34 26.05 q2.13 2.13 0 0.47 q2.13 3.55 1.66 1.42 l2.37 0 l0 0.47 q1.89 3.55 -1.89 1.42 l-3.08 0 z M30.05 113.56 q1.89 3.31 -1.66 1.42 l0.71 -2.37 q2.6 0.95 1.66 -1.42 z M41.38 118 q0.71 2.13 -1.89 -1.42 l-0.95 -3.55 q1.89 0.24 -2.36 -1.89 l-4.96 0 l0.24 -0.47 q2.6 0.71 1.89 -1.42 l5.44 0 q3.78 2.13 1.89 1.42 l0.95 3.54 q2.83 4.02 2.36 1.89 l1.65 0 l0.24 0.71 q2.6 3.31 -0.94 1.18 l-3.54 0 z M36.37 107.68 l2.6 -2.6 q2.83 1.42 0.47 -1.65 l-2.36 -10.15 q1.89 0.24 -0.71 -1.89 q2.12 2.12 -0.24 0.24 l-2.36 2.36 q1.89 2.36 -0.47 0.47 t-0.47 1.65 l-2.12 10.15 q2.12 2.83 0.24 1.42 t1.42 0.71 l2.83 0 q3.07 2.12 0.94 -0.24 z M37.5 107.08 l0 -0.47 l0.94 0 l-0.94 0.71 l0 -0.24 z M39.62 104.94 q2.59 3.54 -0.94 1.41 l-1.18 0 l-1.65 -6.6 l1.18 -5.66 z M36.78 106.8 l-0.94 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.18 -1.41 l0.94 -3.77 z M35.59 99 l-0.71 -2.83 l1.65 -1.65 z M32.29 108.41 l2.36 -11.08 l0.71 3.06 l-1.18 5.18 q2.12 3.06 0.24 1.41 t1.41 0.71 l1.18 0 l0.24 0.71 q2.59 3.53 -0.94 1.41 l-2.83 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.18 -1.41 z M76.56 88.11 l-3.3 0 q1.18 2.12 -2.12 0.94 l-2.59 2.59 q1.65 2.83 -0.94 1.18 l-2.12 5.89 l-3.06 -8.48 q1.65 0.24 -2.59 -1.88 l-3.77 0 q1.65 2.12 -1.18 0.24 l-3.06 3.06 q1.88 2.59 0 1.41 l7.06 17.66 q3.06 3.77 0.71 3.3 l0 7.77 q2.35 3.06 0.71 1.41 t1.41 0.71 l3.3 0 q3.3 2.12 1.41 -0.71 l2.83 -2.83 q3.06 1.65 0.71 -1.41 l0 -7.77 q2.35 0.47 0.71 -3.3 l7.77 -17.66 q2.59 1.65 0 -0.71 q2.35 0.94 -1.41 -1.41 z M67.58 122.44 l-1.88 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.41 -1.41 l0 -7.77 q2.35 0.24 -0.71 -3.53 l-6.59 -16.25 l1.18 0 q4 2.12 2.12 1.41 l3.77 10.36 q2.83 3.3 0.71 0.94 l0 0 q2.83 2.12 0.47 -0.24 l2.83 -2.83 q2.59 1.88 0.47 -0.71 l3.53 -8.95 l3.3 0 q3.77 2.12 0.71 1.18 l-7.77 18.13 q1.65 4 -0.71 3.53 l0 6.36 z M68.06 104.09 q2.59 2.59 0.47 0.71 l-1.18 1.18 z M71.13 96.8 q2.83 1.18 1.65 -1.41 l-3.3 8.71 q2.36 2.59 -0.47 0.47 q2.36 2.12 -0.24 -0.47 l-0.24 -0.71 z M62.66 92.81 q4 2.12 2.12 1.41 l3.53 9.66 l-1.41 3.53 q2.36 2.59 -0.47 0.47 q2.36 2.12 -0.24 -0.47 l-3.77 -10.6 q1.89 0.24 -2.83 -1.89 l-1.41 0 l-0.47 -0.94 q1.89 0.94 0.94 -1.18 l4.01 0 z M57.74 95.45 l0.24 0.71 l-1.65 0 l1.18 -1.18 q2.59 2.36 0.24 0.47 z M68.6 130.13 l-3.54 0 q0.94 2.36 -1.41 -1.41 l0 -8.02 q2.59 0.24 -0.71 -3.77 l-7.55 -18.63 q1.89 0.94 0.94 -1.18 l2.12 0 l6.84 17.22 q3.07 4.01 0.71 3.54 l0 8.02 q2.59 3.3 0.71 1.65 t1.65 0.71 l1.89 0 l0 0.71 q2.6 3.78 -1.42 1.42 z M71.73 129.55 l0.71 0 l-0.71 0.71 l0 -0.71 z M83.31 97.01 l-8.26 18.88 q1.89 4.01 -0.71 3.78 l0 8.26 q2.6 3.78 -1.42 1.42 l-0.71 0 l0 -6.85 q2.6 0.47 0.71 -3.54 l8.27 -18.89 q2.6 1.89 0.24 -0.71 q2.6 0.94 -1.65 -1.42 l-3.07 0 l0.24 -0.71 q3.07 0.71 2.13 -1.65 l3.54 0 q4.02 2.36 0.95 1.18 z " fill="none" stroke="black"></path>
</svg>    

<script>
let  bb = captcha.getBBox();
console.log(bb);
</script>
```

**Красная рамка это границы холста SVG**

Подставляете значения из консоли в **viewbox="-45.5 71.2 130.4  60.1"**

Оборачиваете SVG с помощью `<figure>`, задаете ширину и высоту в относительных единицах и получаете полноценный, масштабируемый элемент для вёрстки в HTML

```css
.container {
  width:20vw;
  height:20vh;
}
```

```html
<figure class="container">
<svg width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" viewbox="-45.5 71.2 130.4  60.1"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid red;">
  <path id="captcha" d="M-29.7 80 l-2.19 0 q1.25 1.87 -1.56 0.62 l-1.87 1.87 q1.24 2.18 -0.62 0.93 l-0.93 4.35 l-1.24 -6.2 q1.55 0.31 -1.86 -1.55 l-2.17 0 q1.24 1.85 -0.93 0.31 l-2.16 2.16 q1.54 2.16 -0.31 1.23 l4.31 15.69 q2.15 3.07 0 2.46 l-1.23 3.99 q1.84 1.84 0 0.31 q1.84 3.06 1.22 1.22 l2.45 0 q2.75 1.83 1.53 -0.92 l1.83 -1.83 q2.44 1.22 0.61 -0.91 l6.08 -22.19 q1.82 1.52 0 -0.3 q1.82 0.61 -1.21 -1.21 z M-36.94 104.43 l-2.12 0 q0.91 1.81 -0.91 -0.91 l1.21 -3.92 q2.41 0.3 0 -2.71 l-3.91 -14.44 l0.6 0 q3.01 1.8 1.5 1.2 l2.4 10.8 q2.1 2.1 0.3 0.3 t0.3 0 l1.79 -2.09 q2.09 1.49 0.3 -0.6 l2.09 -9.84 l1.49 0 q2.98 1.79 0.89 1.19 z M-35.99 92.16 l-1.49 1.49 l0.89 -3.86 z M-35.31 83.04 q2.08 0.59 1.48 -1.18 l-2.07 9.17 l-0.59 -2.66 z M-41.96 79.76 l2.07 0 q3.25 1.77 1.47 1.18 l1.47 7.36 l-1.18 4.71 l-2.06 -10.29 q1.47 0.29 -2.06 -1.47 l-0.59 0 l-0.29 -0.59 q1.76 0.59 0.88 -1.17 z M-43.3 81.02 l0 0.58 l-0.88 0 l0.88 -0.58 q2.04 1.75 0 0.29 z M-41.07 106.28 q0.87 1.75 -0.87 -0.87 l1.16 -4.07 q2.32 0.29 0 -2.9 l-4.06 -15.36 q1.74 0.58 0.87 -1.16 l1.16 0 l3.76 14.45 q2.31 2.89 0 2.6 l-1.15 4.04 q1.73 2.02 0 0.29 q2.02 2.88 1.44 1.15 l2.01 0 q1.72 2.01 0 0.57 q1.72 2.87 -1.43 1.15 l-2.58 0 z M-28.63 80.71 l-6.29 22.31 q1.72 2.57 -1.43 1.14 l6 -21.12 q2 1.43 0 -0.29 q1.99 0.57 -1.42 -1.14 l-1.42 0 l0 -0.28 q2.27 0.57 1.42 -1.14 l1.99 0 q3.12 1.7 0.85 1.13 z M-7.36 97.1 q1.42 0.28 -0.57 -7.35 q1.98 -2.54 -3.11 -5.08 l0.28 -0.28 q4.8 0.28 3.1 -5.92 q1.97 -1.13 -2.53 -4.78 t-5.35 -1.97 l-7.03 0 q1.4 1.69 -1.4 0.56 l-2.24 2.24 q1.4 2.24 -0.56 1.12 l0 22.96 q1.96 2.52 0.56 1.12 t1.12 0.56 l2.51 0 q2.51 1.67 1.39 -0.56 l1.95 -1.95 q2.51 1.11 0.56 -1.11 l0 -6.4 q4.45 2.5 2.5 5.28 q1.94 3.33 0.28 3.61 q2.22 3.33 1.94 1.66 l3.6 0 q2.22 1.66 0.28 0 l2.21 -2.21 q2.21 1.38 0 -0.28 z M-9.66 99.36 q1.66 1.1 -0.28 -1.65 l1.65 0 z M-8.54 90.04 q1.93 7.15 0.55 7.15 l-2.2 0 q1.65 -0.55 -0.27 -4.94 q1.92 0 -0.82 -3.29 q0.82 0 -2.74 -1.92 q3.56 1.09 2.46 -1.64 q4.92 2.46 3.01 4.65 z M-18.58 87.4 l-1.91 1.91 q1.36 2.46 -0.55 1.36 l0 6.81 l-1.63 0 q0.82 1.63 -1.09 -1.09 l0 -22.02 l5.98 0 q4.62 1.63 4.89 1.9 t2.17 4.61 q1.9 3.8 -0.54 3.52 q1.35 1.9 -1.62 0.81 l-1.89 1.89 q1.62 1.89 -0.27 0.27 q1.89 2.16 1.08 0.54 t2.16 1.08 q2.97 2.97 1.08 3.5 q1.89 4.31 0.27 5.12 l-1.08 0 q0.81 1.61 -1.34 -1.08 q1.61 -0.27 -0.27 -3.49 q1.88 -4.29 -4.02 -5.9 q1.34 1.61 -1.34 0.54 z M-19.02 88.91 l0 0.54 q1.61 1.61 -0.53 0 z M-12.56 85.79 q2.14 1.87 0.53 0 q1.07 2.67 -1.87 1.33 z M-15.73 72.77 q4.53 1.86 5.06 1.86 t2.4 4.52 q1.86 5.59 -2.13 5.32 q2.39 0.53 0.53 -3.19 q1.86 -1.06 -2.39 -5.04 t-5.31 -2.12 l-6.1 0 l0 -0.53 q1.85 0.53 1.06 -1.06 l7.15 0 z M-24.6 74.58 l-0.53 0 l0.53 -0.53 l0 0.53 z M-25.34 100.83 q0.79 1.85 -1.06 -1.05 l0 -23.19 q1.84 0.53 1.05 -1.05 l0.53 0 l0 22.1 q1.84 2.37 0.53 1.31 t1.31 0.53 l1.58 0 l0 0.52 q1.84 2.89 -1.31 1.05 l-2.62 0 z M-20.96 99.29 l0.52 0 l-0.52 0.52 l0 -0.52 z M-19.35 97.8 q1.83 2.88 -1.05 1.05 l-0.52 0 l0 -6.79 q1.83 0.52 1.04 -1.04 q2.35 1.82 0.52 0 l0 6.77 z M-15.36 100.22 q1.56 -0.26 -0.26 -3.64 q1.82 -3.12 -3.12 -5.72 l0 -0.78 q2.08 1.3 0.26 -0.78 t0.78 -0.26 q5.71 1.82 3.63 5.44 q2.07 3.37 0.26 3.63 q2.33 3.37 1.81 1.55 l1.03 0 q2.07 2.84 0.26 1.81 l-3.62 0 q0.77 1.81 -1.55 -1.29 z M-17.29 86.17 l2.06 -2.06 q3.35 0.26 1.55 -2.83 q2.06 -2.06 -3.09 -3.86 l-1.03 0 q1.29 1.8 -1.29 0.51 l-2.31 2.31 q1.54 2.31 -0.51 1.28 l0 4.36 q2.05 2.57 0.51 1.28 t1.03 0.51 q3.59 1.79 3.08 -1.54 z M-17.93 78.11 l1.02 0 q4.61 1.79 2.56 3.33 q2.05 3.58 -1.79 3.07 q2.04 1.53 0 -0.77 q2.04 -1.79 -3.06 -3.83 l0 -0.51 q2.04 0.51 1.27 -1.27 z M-19.62 80.27 l-0.51 0 l0.51 -0.51 l0 0.51 z M-19.09 80.91 q4.32 1.78 2.54 3.31 q2.03 2.29 -0.25 1.02 q1.27 2.03 -1.27 0.25 q1.02 1.78 -1.01 -1.27 l0 -3.3 z M-20.54 87.96 q1.01 1.77 -1.01 -1.27 l0 -4.56 q2.03 0.51 1.27 -1.27 l0.51 0 l0 3.29 q2.02 2.53 0.51 1.26 t1.01 0.51 q2.53 1.77 1.01 -0.25 q0.76 3.78 -3.28 2.02 z M-2.52 78.67 q0.25 3.53 -2.27 5.04 q1.76 3.78 -0.25 6.55 q2.01 6.04 0.25 6.29 q2.52 5.53 2.26 5.53 q4.27 4.02 7.04 2.26 q2.76 1.76 2.26 0 t2.26 0 l5.02 0 q2.76 1.76 1 -0.5 l2.51 -2.51 q2.51 1.25 0.5 -1.25 l0 -1.25 q2 1.25 -0.5 -1.25 t-1.25 -0.5 l-1 0 q1.5 1.75 -2 0.5 q4.5 -1 2.5 -9.74 q2 -3 -0.25 -6.74 q1.5 -1.5 -2.25 -5.24 q-0.25 -0.5 -6.98 -2.24 q-2.74 1.74 -6.98 2.49 z M15.94 98.89 l1 0 q3.24 1.74 1.24 1.24 l0 1.24 q1.99 2.98 -1.24 1.24 l-0.75 0 q1.99 0 -1.74 -1.74 l-0.99 0 q1.49 1.74 -1.99 0.5 q2.73 1.24 1.49 -1.49 q2.48 1.74 1.24 -0.5 t1.49 -0.5 z M16.85 103.56 l-0.5 0.5 l0 -0.5 l0.5 0 z M13.86 92.3 q1.98 8.16 -2.23 9.15 l-0.99 0.99 q1.73 1.98 0 0.49 q1.98 1.98 0.25 0 q2.22 1.73 1.48 -0.49 t1.48 -0.49 l0.99 0 q3.21 1.73 1.23 1.23 l-3.94 0 q1.23 1.72 -2.46 0 t-2.46 0 q-2.71 1.72 -6.89 -1.97 q0.49 0.25 -2.21 -5.41 q1.72 -0.25 -0.25 -6.15 q1.97 -5.9 1.47 -10.57 q4.18 0.74 5.4 -1.23 q6.63 1.96 6.63 2.21 q3.68 3.68 2.21 5.15 q2.45 3.92 0.25 6.87 z M14.47 93.42 q1.96 -2.94 -0.25 -6.86 q1.47 -1.71 -2.45 -5.39 q-0.24 -0.49 -7.1 -2.45 q-0.73 1.96 -4.89 0.73 q4.16 -0.98 7.34 -2.69 q6.6 1.96 6.85 2.2 q3.67 3.67 2.2 5.13 q2.44 3.91 0.24 6.84 q1.95 9.28 -3.17 10.01 q3.17 -0.73 1.22 -7.81 z M9.76 107.81 q1.22 1.95 -2.44 0.24 t-2.44 0.24 q-2.68 1.95 -6.82 -2.19 q0.24 0.24 -2.19 -5.6 q1.7 -0.24 -0.24 -6.33 q2.19 -2.92 0.24 -6.81 q2.68 -1.46 2.19 -5.11 q2.43 1.46 0.73 -0.49 q0.97 4.62 -1.21 9.96 q2.19 6.32 0.24 6.56 q2.67 5.83 2.43 5.83 q4.37 4.13 7.28 2.18 q2.91 1.94 2.43 -0.24 t2.43 -0.24 l4.12 0 l0 0.73 q2.18 3.15 -1.21 1.21 l-5.33 0 z M7.27 82.1 q0.48 1.94 -2.42 0.73 l-2.66 2.66 q1.21 2.9 -1.21 3.39 q1.94 3.63 -0.24 6.05 q2.18 9.91 1.69 9.67 q2.9 2.66 2.42 0.97 q3.62 1.93 2.17 -0.72 l2.66 -2.66 q3.62 0.24 1.69 -9.66 q2.17 -6.28 -1.69 -9.89 q1.21 0.97 -2.41 -0.96 z M1.45 100.57 q1.93 0.24 0 -4.58 q2.17 -6.03 1.45 -9.4 q2.41 1.45 0.96 -0.48 q1.69 4.09 -0.48 7.71 q2.17 9.87 1.69 9.63 q3.13 2.89 2.65 0.96 q1.44 3.85 -2.89 1.92 q0.24 1.92 -2.65 -1.92 q1.68 0.96 -0.72 -3.61 z M7.69 104.55 q0.48 2.16 -2.4 -0.72 q0.72 0.48 -1.44 -9.37 q2.16 -3.84 0.48 -7.68 q3.84 1.68 2.4 0.72 q3.6 3.36 1.44 9.6 q2.16 7.44 -0.48 7.68 z M9.59 104.08 q1.44 2.64 -1.2 0.72 q2.64 -0.24 0.48 -7.43 q2.16 -6.47 -1.68 -10.06 q1.2 0.96 -2.87 -0.96 q2.87 0 2.87 -1.92 q4.07 1.92 2.87 1.91 q2.63 3.11 0.72 3.83 q2.39 3.83 0.24 4.78 q2.15 10.05 -1.43 9.33 z M46.39 109.98 q2.63 1.43 0.24 -1.43 l-7.17 -26.29 q1.67 0.24 -2.39 -1.67 l-5.02 0 q1.19 1.91 -1.91 0.96 l-2.39 2.15 q1.67 2.39 -0.72 0.95 l-7.4 26.49 q2.15 2.15 0 0.48 q2.15 3.34 1.43 1.43 l2.86 0 q3.1 1.91 1.91 -1.19 l1.91 -1.91 q2.86 1.19 0.95 -1.19 l0.48 -2.38 l4.77 0 q3.57 1.91 1.67 1.43 l0.95 3.57 q2.62 3.81 2.38 1.91 l3.33 0 q2.86 1.9 1.19 -0.48 z M37.85 82.35 q3.57 1.9 1.67 1.43 l7.38 26.89 q2.38 2.38 -0.24 0.95 t-0.71 0.48 l-1.19 0 l-7.13 -25.92 q1.66 0.24 -2.38 -1.9 l-4.52 0 l0.24 -0.48 q2.61 0.71 1.9 -1.43 l4.99 0 z M45.14 113.32 l0.95 0 l-0.71 0.71 q2.14 1.9 -0.24 -0.71 z M30.87 107.08 l-2.37 2.37 q1.66 2.61 -0.71 0.95 l-0.71 2.37 l-2.61 0 q0.95 1.9 -0.95 -1.19 l7.12 -26.1 l4.74 0 q3.56 1.9 1.9 1.42 l7.11 26.09 l-1.42 0 q0.71 2.13 -1.9 -1.42 l-0.95 -3.56 q1.66 0.24 -2.37 -1.9 l-5.45 0 q1.18 2.13 -1.9 0.95 z M22.51 116.56 q0.95 2.13 -0.95 -1.18 l7.58 -27.47 q2.61 0.95 1.66 -1.42 l-7.34 26.05 q2.13 2.13 0 0.47 q2.13 3.55 1.66 1.42 l2.37 0 l0 0.47 q1.89 3.55 -1.89 1.42 l-3.08 0 z M30.05 113.56 q1.89 3.31 -1.66 1.42 l0.71 -2.37 q2.6 0.95 1.66 -1.42 z M41.38 118 q0.71 2.13 -1.89 -1.42 l-0.95 -3.55 q1.89 0.24 -2.36 -1.89 l-4.96 0 l0.24 -0.47 q2.6 0.71 1.89 -1.42 l5.44 0 q3.78 2.13 1.89 1.42 l0.95 3.54 q2.83 4.02 2.36 1.89 l1.65 0 l0.24 0.71 q2.6 3.31 -0.94 1.18 l-3.54 0 z M36.37 107.68 l2.6 -2.6 q2.83 1.42 0.47 -1.65 l-2.36 -10.15 q1.89 0.24 -0.71 -1.89 q2.12 2.12 -0.24 0.24 l-2.36 2.36 q1.89 2.36 -0.47 0.47 t-0.47 1.65 l-2.12 10.15 q2.12 2.83 0.24 1.42 t1.42 0.71 l2.83 0 q3.07 2.12 0.94 -0.24 z M37.5 107.08 l0 -0.47 l0.94 0 l-0.94 0.71 l0 -0.24 z M39.62 104.94 q2.59 3.54 -0.94 1.41 l-1.18 0 l-1.65 -6.6 l1.18 -5.66 z M36.78 106.8 l-0.94 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.18 -1.41 l0.94 -3.77 z M35.59 99 l-0.71 -2.83 l1.65 -1.65 z M32.29 108.41 l2.36 -11.08 l0.71 3.06 l-1.18 5.18 q2.12 3.06 0.24 1.41 t1.41 0.71 l1.18 0 l0.24 0.71 q2.59 3.53 -0.94 1.41 l-2.83 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.18 -1.41 z M76.56 88.11 l-3.3 0 q1.18 2.12 -2.12 0.94 l-2.59 2.59 q1.65 2.83 -0.94 1.18 l-2.12 5.89 l-3.06 -8.48 q1.65 0.24 -2.59 -1.88 l-3.77 0 q1.65 2.12 -1.18 0.24 l-3.06 3.06 q1.88 2.59 0 1.41 l7.06 17.66 q3.06 3.77 0.71 3.3 l0 7.77 q2.35 3.06 0.71 1.41 t1.41 0.71 l3.3 0 q3.3 2.12 1.41 -0.71 l2.83 -2.83 q3.06 1.65 0.71 -1.41 l0 -7.77 q2.35 0.47 0.71 -3.3 l7.77 -17.66 q2.59 1.65 0 -0.71 q2.35 0.94 -1.41 -1.41 z M67.58 122.44 l-1.88 0 q0.94 2.12 -1.41 -1.41 l0 -7.77 q2.35 0.24 -0.71 -3.53 l-6.59 -16.25 l1.18 0 q4 2.12 2.12 1.41 l3.77 10.36 q2.83 3.3 0.71 0.94 l0 0 q2.83 2.12 0.47 -0.24 l2.83 -2.83 q2.59 1.88 0.47 -0.71 l3.53 -8.95 l3.3 0 q3.77 2.12 0.71 1.18 l-7.77 18.13 q1.65 4 -0.71 3.53 l0 6.36 z M68.06 104.09 q2.59 2.59 0.47 0.71 l-1.18 1.18 z M71.13 96.8 q2.83 1.18 1.65 -1.41 l-3.3 8.71 q2.36 2.59 -0.47 0.47 q2.36 2.12 -0.24 -0.47 l-0.24 -0.71 z M62.66 92.81 q4 2.12 2.12 1.41 l3.53 9.66 l-1.41 3.53 q2.36 2.59 -0.47 0.47 q2.36 2.12 -0.24 -0.47 l-3.77 -10.6 q1.89 0.24 -2.83 -1.89 l-1.41 0 l-0.47 -0.94 q1.89 0.94 0.94 -1.18 l4.01 0 z M57.74 95.45 l0.24 0.71 l-1.65 0 l1.18 -1.18 q2.59 2.36 0.24 0.47 z M68.6 130.13 l-3.54 0 q0.94 2.36 -1.41 -1.41 l0 -8.02 q2.59 0.24 -0.71 -3.77 l-7.55 -18.63 q1.89 0.94 0.94 -1.18 l2.12 0 l6.84 17.22 q3.07 4.01 0.71 3.54 l0 8.02 q2.59 3.3 0.71 1.65 t1.65 0.71 l1.89 0 l0 0.71 q2.6 3.78 -1.42 1.42 z M71.73 129.55 l0.71 0 l-0.71 0.71 l0 -0.71 z M83.31 97.01 l-8.26 18.88 q1.89 4.01 -0.71 3.78 l0 8.26 q2.6 3.78 -1.42 1.42 l-0.71 0 l0 -6.85 q2.6 0.47 0.71 -3.54 l8.27 -18.89 q2.6 1.89 0.24 -0.71 q2.6 0.94 -1.65 -1.42 l-3.07 0 l0.24 -0.71 q3.07 0.71 2.13 -1.65 l3.54 0 q4.02 2.36 0.95 1.18 z " fill="none" stroke="black"></path>
</svg> 

</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь осталось как-то это добро отправить в виде картинки на пайтоне как-то :)

Comment: Да конечно, только мне кажется тут надо ожидать все таки пока картинка прорендерится. С брузера когда беру код svg он нормально работает в файле .svg 
Видимо все таки проблема в ожидание ajax

Comment: к сожелению данное решение не помогло в python.